# Mongo Upper Bound of Range Not Working, Maybe

Tags: mongodb

In the following explain(), look at the bottom to see the value of `Document.Record.l` where I commented `1.7 ^ 308?`.

Why isn't this value set to `10` as I've set `l` to be between 1 and 9? It's set to **1.7 ^ 308** The fact that such a high upper bound is set concerns me from a performance perspective.

```
> db.collection.find( {"Document.Record" : {$all : [ {$elemMatch: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin",
 "l" : { "$gt" : 0 , "$lt" : 10}} }]}}, {_id : 1}).explain
()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Document.Record.n_1_Document.Record.v_1_Document.Record.l_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 2049,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4706,
        "nscanned" : 4706,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4706,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4706,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 91,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "Document.Record.n" : [
                        [
                                "Name",
                                "Name"
                        ]
                ],
                "Document.Record.v" : [
                        [
                                "Kevin",
                                "Kevin"
                        ]
                ],
                "Document.Record.l" : [
                        [
                                0,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308 /* 1.7 ^ 308! */
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Doesn't Matter"
}
```

>

Comment: What is the output of `db.collection.find( {"Document.Record" : {$all : [ {$elemMatch: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"} }]}}, {_id : 1}).count()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a Mongo bug - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10436.

This informative [post](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use) on Mongo indexing led me to this JIRA ticket.

From the JIRA ticket, a Mongo engineer posted:

> please try out the unstable 2.5.3 build that was just released, the index optimizer was thoroughly reworked.